# Datatable check all checkbox after datatable search filter

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

i want to check all checkbox after filter through datatable's search function.
i already implement to checked all checkbox using this code.

```js
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        stateSave: true,
        "bDestroy": true
    });
    
   var allPages = oTable.api( ).cells( ).nodes( );
        $(allPages).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

i want to know if theres any way to check certain chechkbox that filtered through datatable's search. 
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found someway to achieve this problem. 
the main point of this snippet is `oTable.api().rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes()`
hope this thread can help others in the future

```js
 $('#selectAllBTN').click(function () {
        var length = oTable.api().rows({filter : 'applied'}).nodes().length;
        var allPages = oTable.api().rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes();
        for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
         
  $(allPages[i]).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
        }
       
    })
```